# Running Vendor Test Suite(VTS) on Android 8.1

Tags: android, android-source, android-8.1-oreo

I'm trying to experiment VTS on my phone Pixel by following the VTS manual provided by Google. It keeps displaying the error:

```
E/VtsVendorConfigFileUtil: Vendor test config file /config/vts-tradefed-vendor-config-prod.json does not exist
```

I tried to built both on branch master and branch m/android-8.1.0_r1, and both failed. My phone has version Android 8.1.1.

Does anyone have any idea to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

A colleague of mine reported the same error. I noticed after I built the vts target that this config file can be found here:

```
${ANDROID_BUILD_TOP}/vendor/google_vts/harnesses/tradefed/res/config/vts-tradefed-vendor-config-prod.json
```

Try copying this into the directory where you're executing the vts tests

Comment: This is not really an answer. Suppositions should be posted as comments.

Answer (score 0):

Please give a try with the latest Version. Most probably this issue is not seen in latest VTS version.